# Syntax for assigning variable in makefile via $(if ...)

Tags: if-statement, makefile, variable-assignment

The following lines in a Makefile show, via the output of the echo, that the various syntaxs that were tried for the assignment of $(if ... ) are all incorrect (the three variants of $(if...) shown below are only some of the variants I tried):

```
exes  =  $(patsubst %.cc,%.exe,$(wildcard *.cc))    

#depends_on = $(ifeq "$@" "the_file.exe",fooinc.h,nothing)    
#depends_on = $(if (ifeq($@,the_file.exe),1,0),`echo true $@`,`echo false $@`)    
depends_on = $(if "a" eq "ha",fooinc.h,nothing)    

all:  ${exes}     

%.exe:%.cc       
    @echo depends on: $(depends_on)      
    $(VERBOSE)${gcc} ${flags} ${INC}  -o $@  $<
```

Documentation for gnu makefile explains the syntax for multi-line if ... else .. endif, but I have not been able to find any explanation for the single line $(if ...).

Update:  @MadScientist 's explanation and illustration do answer the question asked above.  To fully achieve the desired functionality, one needs the concept of [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion);  this is illustrated below -- note the .SECONDEXPANSION:, the double $ used for expanding depends_on, and the $^ (rather than $<) in the echo action:

```
depends_on = $(if $(filter the_file.exe,$@),fooinc.h,)  

.SECONDEXPANSION:  
%.exe: $$(depends_on)  %.cc     
    @echo depends on: $(depends_on) carat: $^  ampersand: $@      
    $(VERBOSE)${gcc} ${flags} ${INC}  -o $@  $<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the if function says it expands its first argument and if the result is the empty string, it's false.  If it's not the empty string, it's true.

So you have to find a way to construct a statement which, when evaluated, will expand to a non-empty string if you want the then-part and an empty string if you want the else part.  If you're doing string comparison with a single word then `$(filter ...)` is a good option:

```
depends_on = $(if $(filter the_file.exe,$@),fooinc.h,nothing)
```